# selenium click on anchor tag inside table td

Tags: selenium

i have my html code looks like this:

```
<div id="food-search-all" class="fd_food_search_all fd_loading" style="display: block;">
     <ul class="fd-breadcrumbs" > 

        <li>
            <a href="Javascript://" class="breadcrumb">Baked beans</a>
        </li>
   </ul>

     <div class="fd-search-results"><table class="results ib-list" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"> 
        <tbody>           
            <tr class="foods foods_s-fndds244535"> 
                <td class="name"> 
                    <a href="Javascript://">Baked beans</a>
                </td>
                <td class="default-amount"> </td> 
            </tr>

            <tr class="foods foods_s-fndds244535"> 
                <td class="name"> 
                    <a href="Javascript://">Chickens</a>
                </td>
                <td class="default-amount"> </td> 
            </tr>
            <tr class="foods foods_s-fndds244535"> 
                <td class="name"> 
                    <a href="Javascript://">Cow milk</a>
                </td>
                <td class="default-amount"> </td> 
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table></div> 
</div>
```

how can i click to the with text `Baked beans` residing inside  table/tr/td/a

i tried this below code,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/table[contains(@class,'results ib-list')]/tbody/tr/td[@class = 'name']/a[contains(text(),"+linktext+")]")).click();
```

but its showing exception:

```
 org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small error in your code, you're missing '' around the text `"+linktext+"`:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/table[contains(@class,'results ib-list')]/tbody/tr/td[@class = 'name']/a[contains(text(),'"+linktext+"')]")).click();
```

`NoSuchElementException` usually means the element is in a `frame`, or slow to load.  Selenium only interacts with elements in the current frame.  Any element within a child `frame` cannot be interacted with until you switch into that `frame`.  You can switch by using `switchTo().frame()`:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(ARG);
```

The arguments for `frame()` are

- number from 0
- id of the `frame`
- the `webelement` rerference of the `frame`

When done in the `iframe`, use the following to exit back to the top of the document:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: tested, still same error..  `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/table[contains(@class,'results ib-list')]/tbody/tr/td[@class = 'name']/a[contains(text(),'Baked beans')]"}`

Comment: @Sundara That's a different exception.  The original exception was an invalid selector exception.  Now you're getting a no such element exception.  That suggests the element is either in a frame or iframe, or slow to load.

Comment: @Sundara I'm guessing your element is in a frame or iframe.  You should be able to find out by looking at the HTML.  Or you could edit your question and add the HTML of the page.

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.linkText(linktext)).click();` will not work for me, you can see in the above code there is already duplicate  hyperlink with same text

Comment: i don'nt know whether i am using frameset or not, i can try if you post a code for frame() to click on that link..

Answer (score 0):

As you have the link under a tag so selenium must work with below code.
You xpath will be `.//*[@id='food-search-all']/ul/li` (assuming that div id is unique .You can take help with firebug for generate xpath )

```
IWebElement TargetElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xPathVal)); 
string CellVal = TargetElement.Text.ToString(); 
TargetElement = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText(CellVal));
TargetElement.Click();
```

---

sometimes sigle use of .Click() not work i will suggest add one more TargetElement.Click(); if your first try not work.