# Unable to locate Element even with waits in table

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to set a WebElement so i can click it with:

`executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", WebElement);`

But when i try to find the element, it just keeps throwing Unable to locate element, i have tried several ways, but it won't find it.

this is the HTML path for the element (td#tab_6)

```
<table id ="menuHolderTable" class="menuGolderTable">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td id="MenuGolderCell" class="MenuHolderCell">
     <table id="MenuTable"class="MenuTable">
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td id="tab_6" class="tab_6">
        </td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
   </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here is my code:

```java
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Loading...')]"))));
WebElement toolTab = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='MenuTable']/tbody/tr/td"));
```

This is the error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: 
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//table[id='MenuTable']/tbody/tr/td"}
>   Command duration or timeout: 36 milliseconds
>   For documentation on this error, please visit: 
> http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Comment: I Found the answer to this issue here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145364/selenium-click-on-anchor-tag-inside-table-td

The problema was not switching frames.

Answer (score 0):

It seems u have missed **@** in this particular LOC,
    WebElement toolTab =     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//**table[id='MenuTable']**/tbody/tr/td"));

Hence you are getting NoSuchElementException.
So make sure u add **@id**.