# Loop click on anchor tags in table but with css selectors python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors

Is there a way to click on specific anchor tags with href BUT only with specific css selectors/text/tags/etc?

This is the link which I want to click through: http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/germany/bundesliga/

NOTE: The table is `table#tournamentTable.table-main`, the one in the middle.

There is a table and I would like to click in each link displayed. (I already know there's something called 'is_displayed' but I haven't arrived to this issue yet so this is not the main problem)

The problem is that, as far as I have tried, I haven't figured out how to click only on the ones which I want! (Which have a unique css selector)

Here is my current code (I will point out where I am struggling):

```
#Load Modules
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from random import randint

#Set profile
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("Set Profile")

#Open driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.get("http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/germany/bundesliga/")


#Find the elements (FIRST IDEA)
list_links=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".name.table-participant")
"""
These ones are not clickable BUT this is the list that I want.
"""
#Print
for i in list_links:
    print(i.text)


#(SECOND IDEA)
list_links=driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('-')
"""
Pretty close I guess, but there are still some 
elements that I don't want
"""
#Print
for i in list_links:
    print(i.text)


#(THIRD IDEA(S)) None of them works
list_links=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'/bundesliga/')]")
list_links=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href=soccer/germany/bundesliga/]')
list_links=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".name.table-participant[class='href']")
"""
I guess I'm pretty close but I can't get the click!
"""
#Print
for i in list_links:
    print(i.text)


#End
```

By the way, I stumbled upon with this: [selenium click on anchor tag inside table td](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145364/selenium-click-on-anchor-tag-inside-table-td)

I know is something related to xpath but...how to combine xpath which includes specific css selectors and also the anchor clickable tags?

Any thoughts?

Comment: You mentioned about _specific anchor tags with href BUT only with specific css selectors/text/tags/_ but you didn't mention which table/frame/portion_of_webpage. How can we know _anchor tags_ from which table/frame/portion_of_webpage are you targeting?

Comment: @DebanjanB thanks for let me know! I've updated the post and the table is `table#tournamentTable.table-main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below line to get all team pairs:

```
 matches = [pair.text for pair in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("td>a[href^='/soccer/germany/bundesliga/']") if pair.text]
```

*Output:*

```
['FC Koln - Dortmund', 'Freiburg - Bayer Leverkusen', 'Hertha Berlin - Hoffenhei
m', 'Mainz - Bayern Munich', 'Schalke - Werder Bremen', 'Wolfsburg - Stuttgart',
 'B. Monchengladbach - RB Leipzig', 'Augsburg - Eintracht Frankfurt', 'Hamburger
 SV - Hannover', 'RB Leipzig - Augsburg', 'Bayer Leverkusen - Hertha Berlin', 'D
ortmund - Hamburger SV', 'Eintracht Frankfurt - FC Koln', 'Hannover - Freiburg',
 'Hoffenheim - Mainz', 'Bayern Munich - Schalke', 'Stuttgart - B. Monchengladbac
h', 'Werder Bremen - Wolfsburg']
```

There are some hidden links in table. If you want to get those links also, try:

```
matches = [pair.get_attribute('textContent') for pair in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("td>a[href^='/soccer/germany/bundesliga/']")]
```

Comment: Amazing those are clickable! Thank you!